# Is there a vendor that sells rare (blue) rings?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

At some point in the game, is it possible to buy rare (blue) rings from a vendor?

It seems like there's a rare ring for every skill in the game, and hanging on to all of them in case I eventually want to use them is a real drag. There's a vendor that sells rare necklaces in Crestwood. Is there an equivalent for rings?

Answer (score 1):

While I believe you can buy rare rings in Val Royeaux and the Hissing Wastes, I would actually recommend that you *not* use any of the ability modification rings as of this moment. Ring mechanics have been discovered to be extremely buggy right now, sometimes they stop giving their effect whenever you change areas, reload, or view a cutscene. Some rings, such as duration extension rings for the taunt abilities and Barrier, simply do not work. Other times, stacking rings actually cancels out the effect.

Essentially, ability rings are simply too unpredictable to be trusted. You'd be better off finding a ring that increases critical chance or something.

Comment: So the ring is supposed to only boost the skill to which it's name matches? I've been putting them all over the place! d'oh